# How can I allow a different user to connect to my session using X11vnc?

Tags: permissions, x11, vnc, x11vnc

I'm trying to use x11vnc to allow users to remote control certain computers. This works fine in general, but there is one aspect I have trouble implementing. I want to restrict access to a specific user account, but the user that the X11 session belongs to is a different one.

So the situation is:

- User A is logged in at the computer
- User B starts x11vnc manually from the shell
- VNC-client V connects from somewhere to it

The problem is that I can only start x11vnc as root or as the currently logged in user, it doesn't work as any other user. Is there any way to allow a specific user to access my X11 session?

Answer (score 5):

X displays are protected by a "key" which you need to give in order to be able to connect. That key will generally be stored in the user's `~/.Xauthority` file.

To allow someone else's application (like x11vnc) to connect to his DISPLAY, a user has to give him that key or grant him access to his `~/.Xauthority` file. You can retrive the key of your display by doing.

```
xauth list "$DISPLAY"
```

You can grant access to your `~/.Xauthority` by changing its permissions (group ownership or ACLs).

The other user can specify which *authority file* to use via the `XAUTHORITY` environment variable, or add a key to a specific display to his own `~/.Xauthority` using `xauth add`.

Answer (score 2):

If your problem is that `x11vnc` can't even launch because it doesn't have access to the X session, you need to grant access to the other user with `xhost +SI:localuser:other_username` before starting `x11vnc` as the other user.

The title of the question makes it sound like you want to restrict access to the VNC server though.

Comment: It is likely `xhost +otherusername` will not do anything because the X server isn't listening to TCP connections.

Comment: cool.Thanks. I learnt something new today thanks to you (si:localuser). It seems it's not even Linux specific.